# Returning function - Undefined notice error - downloading csv file

Tags: php, sql, csv

```
function get_description($table, $id){
    global $conn;

    if ($id!='') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id=".$id;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!$result) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) {

    }else{
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $description = $rows['description'];

    }

    return $description;
}else{
    return "";
}
}
```

I have this function in my functions.php. I am trying to download an csv file, it does download the csv file, but gives an notice on the header of the csv file

**Notice:**

> Undefined variable: description in
>   **/var/www/html/include/functions.php** on line 73

Line 73 refers to - return $description;

I want to get rid of the notice error on csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You only assign `$description` in certain conditions while you always return it. You should assign it at the beginning of your function with a default value like `NULL`, `FALSE` or in this case probably an empty string.

```
function get_description($table, $id){
    global $conn;
    $description = "";
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You only *sometimes* define the variable:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) {

}else{
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $description = $rows['description'];
}
```

So if the `if` block is executed (not the `else` block), the variable is never defined.  Define it outside of the conditional first, so it always has at least some value:

```
$description = "";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) {

}else{
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $description = $rows['description'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check your code, error message is very straight forward in this case - "Undefined variable: description". It means you are returning undefined variable. If (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) statement is executed in part for positive condition, you are not defining $description variable. Change code to:

```
function get_description($table, $id){
    global $conn;
    $description = "";

    if ($id!='') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id=".$id;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (!$result) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));
        }

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
           $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
           $description = $rows['description'];
        }
    } 
    return $description;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with returning $description as it is not defined in all cases.

Use the below code

```
if( isset($description))
{
   return $description;
}
```